# Sum of particular columns by day of week

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, aggregate-functions

I have bicycle rental data and I have grouped it by number of uses per day using the following code in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', rental_date) FROM rentalinfo;

SELECT
    COUNT(date_trunc('day', rental_date)) as counted_leads,
    date_trunc('day', rental_date) as count_date
FROM rentalinfo
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', rental_date)
ORDER BY date_trunc('day', rental_date) ASC;
```

The result gives a column called counted_leads which contains number of rentals per day. I want to make a query where I can extract and sum the number of rentals on weekends and weekdays separately. I tried for weekdays:

```
SELECT SUM(counted_leads) AS sum_date WHERE count_date NOT IN ('2021-12-04',..)
```

But it I get an error saying "ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT".

How can I fix it, please?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to provide detailed help without knowing your input data, table structure and expected outcome. The last query you've mentioned is incorrect because of missing FROM.

Comment: You should also avoid checking hardcodes dates to find out if a day belongs to a weekend or not. There are functions to check this.

Comment: Where is your from clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `extract(dow ...)` in the where clause to filter all weekday (or weekend) rows and count them:

```
select count(*) as weekdays
from rentalinfo
where extract(dow from rental_date) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Or use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(case when extract(dow from rental_date) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) then 1 end) as weekdays
     , count(case when extract(dow from rental_date) in (0, 6) then 1 end) as weekends
from rentalinfo
```

Comment: shouldn't it be 2,3,4,5,6 for weekdays and 1,7 for weekends? Thank you.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT says `dow` returns Sunday = 0 and Saturday = 6. I think the `isodow` uses 1 to 7.